# Creating/modifying files in NSDocumentDirectory is prohibited by Apple?

Tags: iphone, ios, rules

Two weeks ago I've read a strange article on the internet (russian), I didn't understand clearly, but what I understand it says that Apple prohibited iOS developers from creating/modifying files in the Documents folder! We do it like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.txt"];
```

Is it true? Can anyone explain those new rules announced by Apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [Apple's file system programming guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/Introduction/Introduction.html). What I'm hearing is that files in the Documents directory are available to the user. If you're putting private files there that aren't truly documents (such as a word-processing document, an editable graphics document, etc), then you might need to use the Library directory instead.

Specifically, you should read [Determining where to store your app-specific files](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW11).

Comment: I want to create a plist file programmatically, can't I use NSDocumentDirectory anymore?!

Comment: Did you really read that entire programming guide in 10 minutes?

Comment: I will read it, now I need quick answer.

Comment: I gave you a quick answer: "use the Library directory instead."